# zerofree on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, disk-usage

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 for development on VM VirtualBox on windows 10 pro host
I've compacted the virtual hard drive previously by following the steps from here:
https://www.howtogeek.com/312883/how-to-shrink-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-and-free-up-disk-space/

apart from the usual updates - I have not messed around with it, (recently just had installed the update for virtualbox gues additions)

previously, I only had one /dev/sda1 showing up - today I had three and when I attempt to run zerofree on any of those, I get that the device is mounted in rw

[image]

I have followed some instructions here as well to stop some services and try to remount- but it didnt work

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42015/mount-is-busy-when-trying-to-mount-as-read-only-so-that-i-can-run-zerofree

it still says mount point is busy

I'm unsure if this happened because of a recent update ?
I also tested by uninstalling the vmware guest additions - but it didn't work

Suggestions ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but I see only one `/dev/sda1` and do not see three.  There is a /dev/sda1 which is your / (or system files), a /dev/sda2 for you boot (or /boot/ files, kernel & with more limited encryption [if used]) and /dev/sda3 for user files /home/ - but this to me is a pretty standard setup which can be chosen at install.  Either way I do not see three `/dev/sda1` mentions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What worked for me (combining answers from several related questions and forums):

- VirtualBox 5.2.10
- Windows 10 as Host OS
- Ubuntu 18.04 as Guest OS

First install zerofree:

```
sudo apt-get install zerofree
```

Create 0s to get space to be reclaimed(delete all files you don't need as well as empty the trash)

Reboot to GRUB menu (Press Esc as Ubuntu is booting up)

```
Advanced options for Ubuntu > Recovery Mode (choose highest version number)
```

From the `Recovery Menu`  select `Drop to root shell prompt`

df to get your partitions(to see the partition you want to shrink e.g. sda1, sda 4 etc. usually its `/dev/sda1`)

```
df
```

Try to run `zerofree`

```
zerofree /dev/sda1
```

### Partition is read-write, needs to be mounted as read-only for zerofree to run Error:

If you get an error from zerofree like `/dev/sda1` is mounted as rw, then you need to mount it as read-only to continue.

To mount the `/dev/sda1` or your desired partition as read-only to use `zerofree` on it:

**Note 1:** you should perform the following steps relatively quick to be able to mount the drive as `ro` before services and sockets go back into use and start writing to the disk again. Otherwise you may need to perform the `systemctl` step again to make sure writing to the disk has stopped.

**Note 2:** (Skip reading this until the steps following this fail).Depending on your system, **you may have other services and sockets still writing to disk other than `systemd-journald`**. If the below steps are not working try to see whats still writing to disk after you run the steps and then **stop them** too in the same way.

```
systemctl --type=service
systemctl --type=socket
```

### **Steps:**

**Update:** User @Kevin gave an excellent suggestion to execute the steps ( see below) in a one liner command in case the services and sockets go back into use too fast:

```
systemctl stop systemd-journal* \
&& sudo swapoff -a && mount -n -o remount,ro -t ext2 /dev/sda1 / \
&& zerofree -v /dev/sda1
```

First, **stop all processes writing to the disk** so you don't get `mount /: mount busy` error

```
systemctl stop systemd-journald.socket
systemctl stop systemd-journald.service
```

Check if any swap partitions are enabled:

```
swapon -s
```

If enabled, then disable them

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Then finally you should be able to mount `dev/sda1` as read-only. (Your filesystem type might be different from `ext2`. To find the filesystem, run `df -T`)

```
mount -n -o remount,ro -t ext2 /dev/sda1 /
```

Then finally run `zerofree`

```
zerofree -v /dev/sda1
```

Whens `zerofree` is done, shutdown Ubuntu

```
halt
```

Then finally, on the Host OS (in my case Windows 10), compact the vdi to reclaim space:

```
VBoxManage.exe modifymedium disk "C:\path\to\disk.vdi" --compact
```

Comment: Excellent suggestions : systemctl stop + swapoff. They were they keys to my locks

Comment: I kept getting `mount: / is busy` after the mount command, and stopping the other services mentioned in this other question resolved it for me (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42015/mount-is-busy-when-trying-to-mount-as-read-only-so-that-i-can-run-zerofree) (`service rsyslog stop && killall dhclient`)

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, the last step of your solution "modifymedium", when applied to my case never runs and stays at 0% forever. I don't know why! What is the reason?

Comment: @Ash Could be a bug.. What version of VirtualBox are you using? Try using a different (newer) version of VirtualBox (earlier versions of VB use `modifyhd` or `modifyvdi` for example instead of `modifymedium`).

Comment: Weirdly, it worked when I tried it for a second time:)

Comment: But, what is harder to do is actually to resize my .vdi file from a very huge virtual size. Neither the VB has such a capability nor the windows is allowing to use modifymedium --resize.

Comment: `killall dhclient` was what did it for me.

Comment: I executed the following on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: `systemctl stop systemd-journal* && swapon -s && sudo swapoff -a && mount -n -o remount,ro -t ext4 /dev/sda<your number> /` ... 
I used only one stop command and it works: `systemctl stop systemd-journal*` ...

Answer (score 24):

**install zerofree**

`sudo apt install zerofree`

**reboot into ubuntu recovery console, hold down [RIGHT SHIFT]**

`advanced options -> recovery mode -> root console`

**find the root directory**

`mount | grep "sda"`

**run zerofree**

```
echo "u" > /proc/sysrq-trigger
mount /dev/mapper / -o remount,ro
zerofree -v /dev/sda1
```

**reboot**

`shutdown -r now`

**compress the drive**

`VBoxManage modifyhd /path/to/VDI/VM.vdi --compact`

source: cyplex from ubuntuforums.org

Comment: the `echo "u" > /proc/sysrq-trigger` seemed to made the difference in my case. every other tip I read with stopping various services, killing dhclients, disabling swap, was not sufficient

Comment: this one actually works with 20.04

Comment: This one actually works with 21.04

Answer (score 13):

I used Emmanuels' solution and it only worked after stopping two more sockets:

```
systemctl stop systemd-journald.socket
```

new lines:

```
systemctl stop systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
systemctl stop systemd-journald-audit.socket
```

```
systemctl stop systemd-journald.service
sudo swapoff -a 
mount -n -o remount,ro -t ext4 /dev/sda1 / 
zerofree /dev/sda1
```

Note: I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 and EXT4

Shrunk my disk from 40 GB to 7 GB. Thanks. :)

Comment: I had 'haveged' installed and running due to an entropy issue we experienced once, had to stop that service as well. Adding the additional line `systemctl stop haveged.service` in addition to these four systemctl stops did it for me.

Comment: It Works! Thanks a lot, your solution ends with 5 hrs of torture

Comment: It worked for me from above solutions . Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in one of the comments, you have three partitions mounted (sda1, sda2 and sda3) and several temporary filesystems used for other purposes.

The manual for `zerofree` indicates that if you want to run this on a filesystem, then that filesystem must be either mounted readonly, or unmounted.  When you are running Ubuntu, it is certain that the root partition `/`, which is `/dev/sda1` on your computer, is mounted thus the command will give a failure.

If you want to run `zerofree` on `/dev/sda1` you will need to either boot from an alternate device, uch as a bootable USB or ISO image, or perform a chroot to an alternate linux image.  The link that you reference has specific instructions for you, on how to run this program on your root partition.  Please re-read their instructions on how to use this program in Linux:

- Boot and access Grub before the OS loads
- Choose 'Advanced Options' from the grub menu
- Enter a recovery mode session
- use the 'root' login
- Identify the disk
- Run `zerofree`
- halt the machine
- powerdown and restart the VM

2019-01-22

The current version Ubuntu makes running `zerofree` difficult from the recovery session - in this case, it is easier to run this program from a live USB:

- Download a current Ubuntu iso file
- Create a live USB / CD with the Ubuntu iso
- Boot your device from the live media (this can also be done in VM's)
- Install the program `zerofree`, if it is not already installed, with the command `sudo apt install zerofree`
- Run the command
- Reboot the machine

Comment: That's what I have done, from GRUB choose root, 
and on /dev/sda1 when I try to run zerofree on /dev/sda1 - it says it's mounted in rw

Comment: is there a way, from GRUB as root - to remount the /dev/sda1 as readonly ? - have already tried - mount -n -o remount,ro -t ext2 /dev/sda1 / - it comes back with / mount is busy

I have actually done this 3-4 times before and it used to work - this time it just says that /dev/sda1 is mounted in rw mode - not sure what changed, the updates ?

Comment: If it were me, I would boot from an ISO like the Ubuntu installation disk, and choose 'Try Ubuntu'.  Then, since I am running from a disk other than my normal disk, I could install `zerofree` and run that on the partitions of the disk.

Comment: Question is, any idea how do I run a boot ISO externally ? my ubuntu is a virtual box :;/

Comment: There is an option in VirtualBox, to mount an ISO as a CD, and then boot from that CD.  Some of these links are older, but the procedure will be very similar.  [https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=55617](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=55617)  or [https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-cdrom.html](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-cdrom.html) or [https://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/](https://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/)

Comment: The procedure you describe with the recovery session does **not** work. Apparently the recovery session by default mounts the root filesystem in rw.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta My understanding is that the behavior of the recovery session has changed somewhat around the release of Ubuntu 18.10 - many people are reporting that they are unable to run fsck on '/' from recovery, for example.  Thus, we are forced to use a live USB or CD to do this instead, as I mentioned about 3 comments ago...

Comment: I use 18.04, so the change is earlier than 18.10 for sure.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Somewhere in there - you will still find lots of answers saying things like "boot to recovery and run fsck..."

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta  Personally, I always keep a live USB around somewhere...

Comment: Can confirm what Charles said. Running Ubuntu Server 20.04, had to boot my VM with it's install ISO then hop on to the shell (go up to options on the install menu), and I was then able to use `zerofree` on the device I wanted. Before this, it was impossible because of rw mount.

Comment: @JoãoCiocca how did you mount the device?  (before execute zerofree command).

Answer (score 5):

I'd add a comment to Charles Green answer but I don't have enough reputation.

When running `zerofree` command, you may get an error saying that the `/dev/sda1` partition is mounted as read-write. In this case you have to remount such partiton as read-only:

```
mount -n -o remount,ro -t ext2 /dev/sda1 /
```

and re-run the `zerofree` command, as described [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-908128.html)

Answer (score 2):

I used Emmanuel's solution and it worked. But for me the service and socket go back too quickly as he mentioned, so after failing a few times I decided to use a chained command to do all the steps in 1 line:

```
systemctl stop systemd-journald.socket && systemctl stop systemd-journald.service && sudo swapoff -a && mount -n -o remount,ro -t ext2 /dev/sda1 / && zerofree /dev/sda1
```

And it worked finally.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it on Ubuntu 18.04 Server guest

1. Put *Ubuntu 18.04 **Desktop** Live CD* in VM's optical drive (make sure boot sequence loads this first)
2. Boot VM, when CD asks: click `Try Ubuntu`
3. Once GUI is up, run terminal
4. `sudo apt install zerofree` and let it install
5. `sudo fdisk -l` and note system HD e.g. `/dev/sda2`
6. `sudo zerofree -v /dev/sda2` and let it finish
7. `halt`
8. ACPI shutdown VM
9. Remove Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop Live CD from VM's optical drive before restarting

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded in shrinking VBox VM Image size by using `dd` instead of `zerofree`.

1. Normal log into Ubuntu (my VM is elementary OS 5.1)
2. Run `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/EMPTY bs=1M`
3. Run `sudo rm -f /EMPTY`
4. Power off: `sudo poweroff`
5. In **host OS** (windows 10) run `VBoxManage.exe modifyhd vbox.vdi --compact`.

My VM file is shrinked form 8GB to 6GB.
NOTE: It is okay to ignore some warning outputs.

The following is full example of my input/output:

In VM:

```
erich@vbox:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/EMPTY bs=1M status=progress
[sudo] password for erich:         
97889812480 bytes (98 GB, 91 GiB) copied, 415 s, 236 MB/s
dd: error writing '/EMPTY': No space left on device
93399+0 records in
93398+0 records out
97934905344 bytes (98 GB, 91 GiB) copied, 415.592 s, 236 MB/s
erich@vbox:~$ sudo rm -f /EMPTY
bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

In host OS:

```
cd <C:/path/to/folder/of/vbox.vdi>
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyhd eOS.vdi --compact
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

Comment: This will work, but there is a reason people want to use `zerofree` instead of `dd` on a VM: dd will fill the entire drive to its maximum capacity, whereas zerofree only zeroes _unused sectors_. So if you have a 2 TB virtual image and only ever used 2 GB of it and have 100 MB to reclaim, dd will grow the image to 2 TB, zerofill will only zero 100 MB and not grow the image. In some situations, it makes a huge difference - like when the amount of space on your host is less than the maximum size your disk may grow to.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 server VMs accessed remotely via phpvirtualbox. There seemed to be a lot of services running.

I tried the various tips mentioned above, but the method quoted by Teoman was the only way I could get the drive mounted ro, and so was able to run zerofree.

(As an aside, there's no point doing this if your VM is encrypted, as compacting the VM cannot work when its encrypted. Which mine are.)

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me. It's better if you add -v on zerofree because the terminal will otherwise look like it's not responding when executing the command. Add -v will display the percentage of the status. The OS is Ubuntu 18.04.4.

```
$ systemctl stop systemd-journald.socket && systemctl stop systemd-journald.service && sudo swapoff -a && mount -n -o remount,ro -t ext4 /dev/sda1 / && zerofree -v /dev/sda1
```

And after I finished the command below, I free the VDI image size from 160G to 25G.

```
VBoxManage.exe modifymedium disk "C:\path\to\disk.vdi" --compact
```